# EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings

Tags: angular, zone, zonejs

I'm working on angular2 "2.0.0-rc.1"
But zoneJS is giving following error

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings.
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:538)
    at zone.js:515
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:323)
    at Object.NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke (eval at <anonymous> (vendor.js:335), <anonymous>:45:41)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:322)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:216)
    at zone.js:571
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:356)
    at Object.NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvokeTask (eval at <anonymous> (vendor.js:335), <anonymous>:36:41)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:355)
```

My code is as follows

```
let styles   = require('./dashboard.css');
let template = require('./dashboard.html');
declare var zingchart:any;

@Component({
  selector: 'dashboard',
  directives: [ RouterLink, CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES ],
  template: template,
  styles: [ styles ]
})
```

Comment: could you show whats the code ?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:
let styles   = String(require('./dashboard.css'));

It work for me.
Since styles required a string[], parse styles to String().

Answer (score 4):

I think that you did a wrong configuration of the `styles` attribute in a component. This should be something like that:

```
@Component({
  (...)
  styles: [`
    .card {
      height: 70px;
      width: 100px;
    }
  `]
})
```

See this link for more details:

- https://scotch.io/tutorials/all-the-ways-to-add-css-to-angular-2-components

**Edit**

If you want to include CSS files use the following:

```
@Component({
  (...)
  styleUrls: ['css/style.css']
})
```

Comment: `require` loads a module or a JSON file. It's not the case for a CSS file. It won't get a string but an object...

Comment: In your case, I think the `styleUrls` attribute is what you're looking for... I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The error is pretty clear. When you define your component, the `styles` property should be an array and not a string.

See the doc: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html

EDIT: If you want to use a .css file you should use the `styleUrls` property and point to your file.

Comment: But I'm doing the same thing.

Comment: No my friend, we can assign it using variable in style

Comment: You can do what you want but `styleUrls` is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Yes, you are right friend that is working but why not this.

Answer (score 2):

When you do not have a loader defined for your css-files you end up with this error.
Check if you have setup a module-loader in the webpack-configuration like this:

```js
loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: 'raw'
  }
  // ...
]
```

Webpack will not pick files if there's no loader for css-files and will raise this error.
If not already included in your dependencies you need to add the raw-loader to your dev-dependencies with `npm install --save-dev raw-loader`. 
If you use static css files and don't need any processing of course you can use `styleUrls` instead.
To use sass you will need to use this way to load the styles, and can use the loader `raw!sass` for `/\.scss$/`.